# How to make a Promise for initialization, that resolves instantly if initialization already happened?

Tags: javascript, promise

Service workers have this nice functionality - in global scope, there's a promise `navigator.serviceWorker.ready`. You can use that to ensure code is called when the service worker is initialized. Interesting is that it works just as well after the service worker is initialized. You can always do:

```
navigator.serviceWorker.ready.then(function() {/* something */});
```

If worker is ready already, it will fire instantly.

How can I make this kind of initializer promise? For example, in my service worker, I have this code:

```
var cache;
self.addEventListener('install', function(event) {
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open('offline-v1')
      .then(function(c) {
        cache = c;
      })
  );
  event.waitUntil(self.skipWaiting());
});
```

How can I make a global promise `cacheReady` that will be guaranteed to `resolve` with cache object or `reject` if cache has **failed** to init, but the init event fired already? I am looking for **as general solution as possible**. I could make up some ad-hoc code for this, but I want to learn what's the correct promise-based solution to this problem.

Comment: Are you looking for an implementation or just the general possibility to create (and return) a promise that is already resolved?
For creating a resolved promise see: https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/resolve

Comment: It's not possible to determine whether an event has already fired if you're only listening to it after the fact, unless there is a variable/property that tells you that it has.

Comment: What init event are you talking about specifically?

Comment: Isn't `caches.open('offline-v1')` already the promise you're looking for? It resolves with the `Cache` object once ready, and it can be created whereever you want and saved as a global if you want.